# I can't create Question in python manage.py shell.(Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

in models.py i have created class Question and then i want to create Question in models.py shell i am getting an error

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models, migrations

class Question(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    body = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    rating = 0
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True
    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel (
            name = 'question',
            fields = [
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True,
                primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('author', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length = 30)),
                ('body', models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)),
                ('rating', 0),
                ('category', models.CharField(max_length = 10)), 
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

#### shell

```
>>> from f.models import Queston
>>> first_question =  first_question = Question(author = 'testUser', title = 'some question??', body = 'hey this is question body, category = 'some_category')

 File "<console>", line 1
    first_question = Question(author = 'testUser', title = 'some question??', body = 'hey this is question body, category = 'some_category')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an apostrophe missing. Try this instead:

```
first_question = Question(author = 'testUser', title = 'some question??', body = 'hey this is question body', category = 'some_category')
```

If you look at the syntax highlighting in my response and yours, you can see the word 'category' is a different colour, this is an easy way to tell you've made a typo :)

Comment: i have another question than i got another error when i saved it  with command 'first_question.save()'

Comment: @artashessoghomonian If you're happy with the answer, please upvote/ mark the answer as accepted. I also suspect the reason for your error on `first_question.save()` is that you have set category to `"some_category"` which is more than 10 characters and you have set a limit of 10 characters for that field.

Comment: i can't upvote your answer becaouse i dont have rating on stackoverflow, sorry :(

Comment: @artashessoghomonian You should be able to click the tick, by my answer. This will mark it as accepted, and will give you an exra 2 rep :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you Python 2 or 3? If you are Python 2, do this: `raw_input(' ')`. If you are Python 3, do this: `input(' ')`.